# username.website.com OR website.com/username

Tags: dns

I'm developing a new website with membership. Do you think any of these has advantages or disadvantages? I thought today that a mobile version will be available and I was planning m.website.com for that but in "username.website.com" case, this won't work. On the other hand, I think website.com/username is ugly.

I need and also want to know your ideas about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend against populating DNS with many records of the `username.website.com` pattern. -- unless you only plan on having a *very* few users?

Answer (score 1):

From a management standpoint, username.website.com will surely be greater.  You have to create a new DNS record for each user.  In order to do that programatically, you are going to have to manage your DNS with a service that has a API.  I am pretty sure registrars like GoDaddy do not have this.  Amazon has something called [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) that might?

Comment: Even with a cPanel, you can do this subdomain trick. Almost any hosting company provides this here in Turkey. And then a little php code does the routing. But what i really want was your ideas. I think you agree that username.website.com is better, like me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: OK, I did not know about the cPanel trick.  One option would be to allow users to enter http://username.mysite.com/ and redirect them to http://www.mysite.com/username or http://m.mysite.com/username depending on which device they are using.  As for which format I prefer, I think either one looks acceptable :)

Answer (score 0):

`username.website.com` will never work as domain names are propagated via DNS servers and through millions of network devices. Any change to the domain name takes time.

Usually, if you want to handle users you can do something like this: `www.website.com/users/bob` so mobile version will differ only by `m.` prefix.

Comment: An a record "*.website.com" will work. How does tumblr work then without any delay?

Comment: Your point. I haven't seen anything like that in production before.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot harder to make a script that sets up subdomains than it is to make a folder for a user. 
If you have a mobile site, you could fix the m.username.domain.com by making it username.domain.com/m, if you really want the subdomain.
My half a cent.